# multiple toggle menu in a single page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am working on html site for mobile, it is kind of like app style, i have many card with toggle menu which i am talking about. normally we see inside card have toggle menu [image]. it like Material UI type

this is one sample `http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-menu` but i don't want to use any framework that's why i don't use them code. 
another one `https://codepen.io/pagol/pen/pyBoWr`

i did very simply but my problem it is not work multiple button and position problem.

actually i want my each card menu position will be nicely fit on screen. like native app style. i am not sure i can explain properly or not.

my code is here  card html

```
 <div class="cards">
        <div class="img-box"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/170/150/sports" alt=""/></div>
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Interviews</h2>
          <h3>Short description</h3>
       <div class="tmenu"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/menu2-24.png" alt=""/></div>
       <div class="tmenu-items"><ul><li>Add To Playlist</li><li>Share Facebook</li><li>Download Now</li><li>Go To</li></ul></div>
       </div>
        </div>
```

js

```
$(".tmenu").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".tmenu-items").fadeToggle();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.tmenu-items').length)
    {
        $('.tmenu-items').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/8mx7gjjr/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that :

```
$(".tmenu").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.tmenu-items').fadeOut();
    $(this).next(".tmenu-items").fadeToggle();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.tmenu-items').length)
    {
        $('.tmenu-items').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/kw01nap1/2/

Comment: thanks you so much. but it work for click. it suppose to be fadeout another one. meaning if there have any open menu then when click another menu it will close open one. something like one open to another close.

Comment: wow cool. nice. can i ask one more thing . how can open that like https://codepen.io/pagol/pen/pyBoWr

Comment: You can check this exemple its a good start :http://www.cssscript.com/demo/material-inspired-animated-dropdown-menu/#

Comment: thank u so much for your kind suggestion and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use a right context and `.find()` function.

Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/8mx7gjjr/2/

When you click on a card toogle, you need to work on this context (the card you click on). To do this, when you click on the menu toggler, just find the parent of this item. Than, from the parent, go down to find the right menu to open. :)